# Background of JS Prompt

Tags: javascript, image, customization, prompt

I am creating a 10-question quiz based on JS prompts for a website the real developer is busy programming.  That was easy enough to do, but the prompt box is not exactly aesthetically pleasing.  Is there a way to incorporate a background image for the prompt box?

Thanks

Comment: No, you can not. You have to search for an alternative to the prompt box. I'm sure there is a plugin for it.

Comment: Use Bootstrap modals http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE:
[image: IE]

Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

Firefox:
[image: Firefox]

Not only is it ugly, it is also not even close to consistent. Don't use `prompt`.

**Use a real `<form>` instead.**

If you're a more advanced developer, you can try making your own custom `prompt`. My own toolbox has a function called `Dialog` in which I can define text fields, drop-downs, and much much more. Here's a simple example of a `prompt`-like dialog:
[image: PokéFarm Q]

However, as I said, this is relatively advanced. The `function Dialog(...) {...}` code in my source files is filled with features but over 200 lines long, and the dialog shown above is created with the code...

```
Dialog("Hello!","Please answer the question:",
    {type:"input",value:"test",flex:3},
    // flex:3 results in it being three times bigger than the button
    {text:"Submit",onclick:function(inputs) {alert("You said "+inputs[0].value);}},
    {cancelable:true}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the default prompt box no you cannot. Although there are many libraries that offers functionality that is the same of the prompt box: jQuery UI for example: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/